# Spring security remember me failing on IE10

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

Spring security was working fine in all terms except for remember-me feature(simple remember me approach not using persistent approach).

If I log in as a user with the remember me checked and if I close the browser (Chrome) and reopen and hits the same , The app was redirected to the login screen which shouldn't have been the case.

My config xml for spring security had just `<security:remember-me>` 
initially.

Then later I added `<security:remember-me use-secure-cookie="false"/>`
and it worked like a charm in CHROME. So now if the user logs in with the remember me checked and closes the browser and reopens the browser , then the app is redirected with the logged on user to the home page.

But now the same piece of code seems not to work in IE10. And I need it to get done from versions of 9 (IE9 and above). 
Tried a lot scenarios. But cant get to the root cause. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you observe that's different when using IE10 (is the cookie ever set in the browser)? Have you analyzed the content of the requests and responses from the server? Also explain if and how you are using HTTPS.